# Adding year for all records with update_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to update all records in my model by adding another year before the date saved , seek information and an option is with **update_all** , I really would help an example with dates **update_all** database: PostgreSQL

An example:
the saved date is this 15/01/16 after executing the action 01/15/17 and so on all records.

or some other option would be very helpful!

Comment: Please add a database tag, mysql, sqlite3, postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `PostgreSQL` database you can use the `interval` from [`datetime`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) functions:

```
$ rails console
=> User.last
=#<User:0x00563c0ed6e0c0
 id: 7,
 name: "foo",
 email: "foo@test.ru",
 created_at: Tue, 15 Mar 2016 19:54:52 MSK +03:00,
                                            ^^^^
 .......
 => User.update_all("created_at = created_at + '1 year'::interval")
 => #<User:0x00563c0c9e4f78
  id: 7,
 name: "foo",
 email: "foo@test.ru",
 created_at: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 19:54:52 MSK +03:00,
                                              ^^^^
 ........
```

If `MySQL` database you can use the [`DATE_ADD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function.

*All of this should work if the column have a right type.*